# Not able to call processAction of Portlet

Tags: liferay

My game.jsp code -

```
<%@page import="java.io.Console"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />


<script>
    function updateGames() {
        document.getElementById("gameForm").submit();
    }
</script>

<portlet:actionURL name="sampleActionUrl" var="sampleActionUrl">
</portlet:actionURL>

<form id="gameForm" action="${sampleActionUrl}">
    <div onclick="updateGames()">CLICK HERE</div>
</form>
```

My Portlet Code -

```
package com.home;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Game extends GenericPortlet {

    @Override
    @RenderMode(name = "VIEW")
    protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType(request.getResponseContentType());
        PortletContext context = getPortletContext();
        PortletRequestDispatcher rd = context
                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/game.jsp");
        System.out.println("Game.doView() >> rendering");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Game.processAction() >> processAction");


    } 
 }
```

When the Form is submitted on click of the div. 
doView gets called for rendering the portlet, but not the processAction.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code and give  a try

```
<portlet:actionURL name="sampleActionUrl" var="sampleActionUrl"> 
</portlet:actionURL>

<form id="gameForm" action="<%=sampleActionUrl.toString()%>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="env" name="env"/>
    <div onclick="updateGames()">CLICK HERE</div>
</form>

<script>
    function updateGames() {
        document.getElementById("env").value = 'DEV';
        document.getElementById("gameForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

If you are not using JSTL then you can use <%=sampleActionUrl.toString()%> instead of ${sampleActionUrl}

**update** 
remove below piece of code

```
@RenderMode(name = "EDIT")
```

Comment: Still, sysout only from the doView is getting printed. 
I checked for the actionUrl using chrome debug tools... I found the url is - `http://localhost:8080/group/games/gameportal?p_auth=lNGrBu7F&p_p_id=gameAdminTool_WAR_gameAdminToolportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_gameAdminTool_WAR_gameAdminToolportlet_javax.portlet.action=sampleActionUrl`

Comment: the only output on the server console is from doView method.

Comment: i updated the answer.remove @RenderMode(name = "EDIT") as you are not using EDIT mode it seems

Comment: I removed the renderMode annotation... still processAction is not reached

Comment: Yes... I am setting the actionUrl using variable name

Comment: i updated the code as i can see u didn't imported jstl taglib so i changed it to scriptlet and defined method as well.Please check and let me now

Comment: @Gautam... I guess u already mentioned that in ur comments. I did try using scriptlet too.

Comment: Theoretically.. if we submit a form using actionURL, the processAction method gets called, Am i correct?

Comment: yes ,please define method as well  method="post" and then try

Comment: It worked now after adding the method = 'POST'! AH!! Thank you. :)

Comment: np..Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First check that you have set the following in `WEB-INF\portlet.xml`

```
<portlet>

    ...

    <portlet-class>com.home.Game</portlet-class>

    ...

</portlet>
```

Comment: In that case have you tried setting the actionURL with the attribute `portletMode` to EDIT or remove the `@RenderMode(name = "EDIT")` annotation.

Comment: yes.. i tried doing both... still not able to reach processAction